# What options do adepts have for resisting drain?

Tags: magic, shadowrun-sr5, shadowrun

I was looking at taking the Centering metamagic on my adept, before realizing that it specified "magician," and the sidebar at the bottom of CRB p.325 stating that only four metamagics in the book are useful for adepts doesn't include it either.

The sidebar also says that "we'll have plenty more metamagics for you in future supplements," but from what I've found online none of the other books seem to offer any options to help adepts deal with drain. Searching through a list of positive qualities didn't turn up anything either.

So, do adepts have any options for resisting drain other than simply increasing their Body and Willpower?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, there is not another way.**

As of what I can find in the source books, the only option is the one you've mentioned.